# How to skip shipping address and shipping method steps for specific product in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, shipping-address, product-type

I have 2 types of products like electronics & jewelry in our store. I want to skip the shipping method and shipping address step from the checkout page for jewelry type products.

But shipping steps will be displayed for electronics products.

If the cart is blank then it is working but if any product available in the cart then add to cart is not working and the product page is reloading.

plugin code:

```
<?php


namespace Hero\HideShipping\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model;

class Quote
{

    public function afterIsVirtual(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $customType = '';
        $productId = '';
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        foreach ($subject->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
            if ($option = $item->getOptionByCode('simple_product')) {
                $productId = $option->getProduct()->getId();
            }
            $itemProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
            $customType = $itemProduct->getAttributeText('type');
        }
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/yyr.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($customType);
        $logger->info(print_r($subject->getAllItems(),true));
        if($customType == 'Electronic'){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    
}
```

How can I do this? Can anyone suggest a way in Magento 2?

Comment: Try by creating jewelry product as virtual products first. And check 2 scenarios, one by adding only jewelry products in cart and second by adding both electronics and jewelry both. If that doesn't work as per your requirements then you will have to use some 3rd party module or do customizations.

Comment: But I have variation for jewelry products so it will be a configurable product. any other solution?